# Display rootPanel at centre GWT

Tags: css, gwt, gwt-designer

I'm using Google web toolkit to develop a small login page. I'm using GWT Designer. My problem is that the rootPanel is not being displayed at the centre but at the top-left corner of the browser. How can I put it at the centre of the page?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need GWT at all for this, but rather just CSS/HTML.

```
<body>
  <div id="root" style="width: 100px; margin: auto;">
</body>
```

Comment: My mistake, you have to specify a width to make it work.  And this will only center it horizontally, not vertically.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot display the `RootPanel` in the center of the screen since the `RootPanel` is the `<body>` of the document itself, **it has no position.**

What you want is to add a base panel to the `RootPanel` which will be centered horizontally. That new panel (suppose a `FlowPanel`) will hold all other widgets, and that panel can have a position, which means it can be centered.

Something along these lines should do:

```
RootPanel rp = RootPanel.get();
FlowPanel fp = new FlowPanel();

fp.add(allYourWidgets);
fp.addStyleName('center'); // where center is a css rule with "margin: auto;"

rp.add(fp);
```

Comment: RootPanels don't have to be <body> elements. If you specify an ID in RootPanel.get() it will select any element with that ID to be your root panel.

Answer (score 0):

The RootPanel gets a reference to the panel to which all your application widgets must ultimately be added. (RootPanel returns the reference to the document’s body in the browser.) You would generally inject the starting point of your application into an HTML page. You can do this by using the RootPanel class’s get() methods.

Comment: Welcome to SO and if you can please add some code example to explain your solution.